# 50% of all websites suddenly stopped working on my Mac

Tags: network, dns

Today I restarted my Mac (macOS Catalina 10.15.4) and found that around half of all websites are not working.

**How can I debug this further or even fix it?**

### Situation

Here is a short list of a few websites that are (not) working. I am not really seeing any pattern.

| Working | Not working |
| --- | --- |
| `google.com` | `stackoverflow.com` |
| `youtube.com` | `github.com` |
| `wikipedia.org` | `twitter.com` |
| `facebook.com` | `amazon.com` |
| `microsoft.com` | `yahoo.com` |

For the working websites everything is completely normal. For the not working websites my browser tells me `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE` and nothing is loading at all.

The behavior seems to be the same for all working and not working sites respectively.
So I am focusing on `google.com` and `stackoverflow.com` below.

### What I have tried so far without any success:

- different browsers
- several restarts of my laptop
- router restart
- logging in as a different user
- running the wireless diagnostics app, which claims that my connection has no problems
- different DNS Servers (Google `8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4`, Cloudflare `1.1.1.1`, `1.0.0.1`)

### Further observations:

- There are several other devices connected to the same wlan (even another Mac) and all can connect to all websites without any problems.
- Earlier today `microsoft.com` was not working, now it is working.

### Terminal outputs

I do not have too much experience with these command line tools, but maybe the output is helpful.

#### curl: working for some sites

curl **is** working for `google.com`

```
❯ curl https://google.com --output temp
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   220  100   220    0     0   1157      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1157
```

curl **is not** working for `stackoverflow.com`

```
❯ curl https://stackoverflow.com/ --output temp
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: stackoverflow.com
```

#### ping: not working

ping is neither working for `google.com` nor `stackoverflow.com`. This confuses me a bit: I can access `google.com` in a browser, but not `ping` it.

```
❯ ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.184.206): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

```
❯ ping stackoverflow.com
PING stackoverflow.com (151.101.1.69): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
^C
--- stackoverflow.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

### nslookup

```
❯ nslookup google.com
Server:     2a02:8071:b86:2e00:ca52:61ff:febb:8c68
Address:    2a02:8071:b86:2e00:ca52:61ff:febb:8c68#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.250.186.110
```

```
❯ nslookup stackoverflow.com
Server:     2a02:8071:b86:2e00:ca52:61ff:febb:8c68
Address:    2a02:8071:b86:2e00:ca52:61ff:febb:8c68#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.1.69
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.129.69
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.65.69
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 151.101.193.69
```

However, if I specify a nameserver I get a `timeout`

```
❯  nslookup -type=NS google.com 8.8.8.8
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

```
❯  nslookup -type=NS stackoverflow.com 8.8.8.8
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

#### dig

```
❯  dig google.com any

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> google.com any
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47743
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     207 IN  MX  50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     207 IN  MX  30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     207 IN  MX  20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     207 IN  MX  10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     207 IN  MX  40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.

;; Query time: 61 msec
;; SERVER: 2a02:8071:b86:2e00:ca52:61ff:febb:8c68#53(2a02:8071:b86:2e00:ca52:61ff:febb:8c68)
;; WHEN: Sun Oct 10 17:48:18 CEST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 147
```

```
❯  dig stackoverflow.com any

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> stackoverflow.com any
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11209
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;stackoverflow.com.     IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
stackoverflow.com.  300 IN  CAA 128 iodef "mailto:sysadmin-team@stackoverflow.com"
stackoverflow.com.  300 IN  CAA 0 issuewild "digicert.com"
stackoverflow.com.  300 IN  CAA 0 issuewild "letsencrypt.org"
stackoverflow.com.  300 IN  CAA 0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
stackoverflow.com.  300 IN  CAA 0 issue "digicert.com"

;; Query time: 87 msec
;; SERVER: 2a02:8071:b86:2e00:ca52:61ff:febb:8c68#53(2a02:8071:b86:2e00:ca52:61ff:febb:8c68)
;; WHEN: Sun Oct 10 17:48:56 CEST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 241
```

Comment: Try a traceroute to web sites : may be one of the router is faulty somewhere in the middle or a routing table problem . Did you tried using a VPN ?

Comment: Someone pranking you with a child limit?

Comment: @PtitXav traceroute gives the error `traceroute: findsaddr: write: No such process`. Traceroute works fine from other computers in my network.
I cannot connect to my VPN as its domain name cannot be resolved.

Comment: @SolarMike My partner says she's not pranking with my child limit :) That should not be the issue.

Comment: Can you connect to your VPN using its IP address ?

Comment: May be some of the services stopped ipv4, and when you restarted your Mac you reseted the cache of ipv4 names/ip. Check if ipv6 can be activated on your Mac and in your network.

Comment: @PtitXav VPN + IP tells me that it requires a routable IPv4-address. So this is not working either. As your other idea also indicated that this might be related to ipv4/ipv6, I will have a closer look at this.

Comment: I did a reverse DNS  Google and Stackoverflow adresses and it find Google but nothing for stackoverflow

Comment: Have you try update your system version? Mac OS X Catalina version is actually 10.15.7.

Comment: @Jean_JD I can't update right now due to too little storage available.

Comment: I just found a support question at my internet provider's Q&A (https://forum.vodafone.de/t5/St%C3%B6rungsmeldungen-Internet-TV/Not-loading-certain-websites-ipv4-router-adress-not-found/td-p/2451545). Detailing the exactly same problem, which got fixed by replacing the router. So it seems to be my provider's fault. I will call them tomorrow. Thank you all for your help :)

Comment: @A.Z. Hope that’s it for you. Best of luck.

Comment: @A.Z. I/my family made the experience that ISP routers from Vodafone and also Telekom usually perform much worse than other products. We switched to FritzBox long ago and have been very happy.

Comment: I just had this same problem with macos10.14.6. My router was showing an ipv4 had been assigned, but the mac was only showing the ipv6 in ifconfig. I manually assigned the IP the router was showing and everything started working again. Not a permanent solution. So very odd.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but this is how I dealt with the issue:

(same symptoms, half the internet is not accessible, cannot curl / ping / traceroute certain sites)

1. Connected to a different WiFi network - tethered to my mobile in this case.
2. Verified that all the sites can be accessed now.
3. Removed / forgotten the original network.
4. Re-added it and connected again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into pretty much the same issue, except I could access all of the websites on the 2.4G network but not the 5G network. On the 5G network I was sometimes assigned only an IPv6 address and sometimes assigned an IPv4 as well except the router field would be blank. Similar to the fix that Gabriel mentioned, this is how I got around this issue:

1. Go to System Preferences -> Wifi -> Advanced -> TCP/IP
2. Select "Manually" under Configure IPv4.
3. Change the IPv4 to a static address
4. Add the router IP if necessary